# Azure Service Fabric ARM template Provisioning Failed

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a script that facilitates an ARM template to provision an Azure Service Fabric cluster (official windows servers) among other dependencies like storage and such. I do not provision through the portal.

Facts:

1. Two days ago, I used this script to provision the cluster with complete success.
2. I tried the same again yesterday, and the provisioning failed (with the error below).
3. just to reassure you that the provisioning script works, I can successfully provision with this script on other subscription and it constantly and reliably succeeds.

The error:

*Resource Microsoft.Insights/autoscaleSettings '1NodeVMSetAutoScale' failed with message 'The metric with namespace '' and name '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' is not supported for this resource id '/subscriptions/----/resourceGroups/-cluster/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/1'.' 8:10:01 PM - Resource Microsoft.Insights/autoscaleSettings '2NodeVMSetAutoScale' failed with message 'The metric with namespace '' and name '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' is not supported for this resource id '/subscriptions/----/resourceGroups/cluster/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/2'.' 8:10:01 PM - "Template output evaluation skipped: at least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details." 'string' does not contain a definition for 'error'*

**My question is why? What could be the reason for it not to consistently succeed? Can you please help with troubleshooting steps?**

Related info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-autoscale-common-metrics/

Comment: Can you compare your template with this one and see if there's a difference? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-windows-autoscale/  chapter  (bullet point 11 uses the same Perf counter)

Comment: @LoekD thanks for the tip. I will try to compare and let u know if there is a difference. I added more info to my question. Taking the additional info into account, I wonder if you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

2 questions:

1) what region are you deploying in?

2) In the new subscription, can you check what resource providers you have registered, and in what regions? In the [CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/), the commands look like:

```
azure config mode arm
azure provider list
azure provider show  Microsoft.Insights
```

Comment: 1. i am deploying to West US (not 2)

Comment: Can you check what regions that metric is available in for you? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/26/retrieving-resource-metrics-and-creating-alert-rules-via-azure-powershell/

Comment: For "azure provider show  Microsoft.Insights" I get:metrics                    {East US, West US, West Europe, East Asia...}

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue since a week in my subscriptions. The way out was to make changes to the Diagnostic configurations, by adding the counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" under the waddiagnostic performace counters section. You can also take sneak peak here were autoscale is discussed: [Service Fabric Autoscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429938/vmss-with-service-fabric-cluster-autoscale/#39474922)

Please share your template/ part of it to analyse further.

Comment: do u mean add metrics under app insights? can u plz elaborate where exactly to make the changes?

Comment: Please share your template/ part of it to analyse further.